# How to call function for every record in a temp table without using cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a temp table **A** that contains 2 columns (Id, Date).
I need to call a function for every Id in the **A** table, pass the date parameter to the function. As the function outputs records for the previous call, I then need to insert the Id + the output of the function into the table **B**.

The first thing that comes to my mind while dealing with this problem is just using a cursor however, I'm wondering if it could be done another way.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to call a *table valued* function using parameters from other tables:

```
select . . .
from t cross apply
     dbo.func(t.date)
```